# how to install django-scheduler in my project. I am getting an error saying module cannot be imported

Tags: python, django, package, scheduler

I am trying to add the django package know as Django-scheduler in to my project. Please walk me through it by steps as how I have to install it and then run in my project.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's unclear from the documentation on github and readthedocs? From what I can see the github contains a fully working example application.

Comment: could you please share the link ? I don't know how to install into my project. In readthedocs it says currently undocumented.Also it says the Module import error while i run it my project.

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler-sample since it's a sample implementation it might have everything you need. Also the github project page has information about the settings etc. https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am one of the contributors of the django-scheduler project

for install django scheduler on your env please ejecute the following steps:

```
pip instal django-scheduler
```

add to your django **settings.py** the scheduler app (watch out the "r" on project name here!):

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ('schedule',)
```

I just noticed that you need to put as installed app "schedule" instead of "scheduler" (this is going to be fixed in next version.

add to **TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS**:

`"django.core.context_processors.request"`

then sync your db with:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

please provide an example of how you are using the django-scheduler or how you are importing it (I will edit this answer asap).

Comment: I actually kinda dropped it. Now I'm using arshaw-fullcalendar to resolve my purposes. But anyways thanks for you reply. :)

Comment: no problem. if you had any issue and that's why you dropped it out, don't forget to open us a ticket on github or let me know here.

Comment: I too have a problem with this. After installing it, I don't get how to add it to the project or even see how it works. @llazzaro

Comment: @killerbarneydid you try djangoscheduler-sample?